# Token URI of a opensea NFT token is throwing error on GET

Tags: ethereum, opensea

I am trying to fetch the metadata out of a token URI which I found inside an NFT.
The token URI looks like this:

`https://api.opensea.io/api/v2/metadata/matic/<contract_address>/0x{id}`

I tried using the hex form of the tokenId instead of `{id}` but it just returns `{ success:false }` error on GET call.

The tokenId is:
`25301351943351891415725927464477484049512317528648331027932693704579263506192`

The same worked for another token with different token Id, but a different base url:
`https://api.opensea.io/api/v1/metadata/0x495f947276749Ce646f68AC8c248420045cb7b5e/0x{id}`

I observed that the version for the working URL is `v1` and its on a different chain.
Opensea docs doesn't seem to talk anything about `v2`.

Please help me on how to fetch the metadata from the URI mentioned above.

Comment: Apparently opensea website says v2 API is till under progress. But this is so bad